# Error while performing action in WebView

Tags: android, webview, browser, webviewclient, webchromeclient

I'm able load the URL in my `WebView`. But if I perform some action (like click event), I'm getting following error in `LogCat`:

```
Unable to get value of the property 't': object is null or undefinedundefined
```

But if I perform some events from the emulator's browser, it is working fine.

Here is the code, based on the [post](http://www.codeofaninja.com/2011/05/how-to-view-webpage-inside-your-android.html):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

WebView mWebview = null;
String URL = "********";  // Masked intentionally.

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //Not required as per comment given by Raghunandan.

    mWebview  = new WebView(this);

    mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript

    final Activity activity = this;

    mWebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    mWebview .loadUrl(URL);
    setContentView(mWebview );

    }
}
```

Note: Web page is developed using `AngularJS`.

I've added the below property in `Manifiest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: why do you require `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` and your code seems alright. try a different url

Comment: After removing the above line also not working. The web page is created using AngularJS. Does this means do I need to set any other property? Because I've no idea about JavaScript or AngularJS.

Comment: try loading `http://www.google.co.in`

Comment: Yes, Google is loading. Even my site's home is loading. But if I do some action (click event), then I'm getting the error in LogCat, which is not happening in device browser.

Comment: Question was misleading. Updated properly.